# Detect platform in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I am trying to build a cross platform (Mac or iOS) class that needs to work with the native color classes (NSColor or UIColor). I need a way to detect whether I'm on OSX or iOS to change the class I use dynamically. What can I use to detect this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use TARGET_OS_*:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
 //your code
#endif
```

And

```
#if TARGET_OS_MAC

#endif
```

Comment: Great! I knew there would be some symbol. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `TARGET_OS_MAC,TARGET_OS_WIN32,TARGET_OS_UNIX,TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED,TARGET_OS_IPHONE,TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`

Comment: TARGET_OS_WIN32? Cocoa runs on Windows and Unix? Or are those from GCC?

Comment: It is defined in `usr/include/TargetConditionals.h` . About `TARGET_OS_WIN32`this file tells following: `Generate code will run under 32-bit Windows`